# Puppeteer recognized by BET365 during crawler

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am testing a simple Puppeteer script to open a bet365 specific page, but when opened with Chrome for Testing, the website does not loads completely and looks like it hides the html that show the matches

```
let puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { addExtra } = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

const stealth = StealthPlugin();
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete('chrome.runtime')
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete('iframe.contentWindow')

puppeteer = addExtra(puppeteer)
const pluginStealth = StealthPlugin()
pluginStealth.enabledEvasions.delete('console.debug')
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth)

const VIEWPORT = {width: 1200, height: 900};
const BET365 = 'https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R^1/';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            "--disable-infobars",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
            "--incognito"
        ],
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      window.chrome = { runtime: {} };
      delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;
      Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'maxTouchPoints', {
          get() {
              return 1;
          },
      });
      navigator.permissions.query = i => ({then: f => f({state: "prompt", onchange: null})});

    });

    page.viewport(VIEWPORT);
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3.1 Safari/605.1.15');

    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()       
        await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies')

    await page.goto(BET365, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
})()
```

[image]

But it works normal if i open the link in a regular browser
Does somebody know how can i bypass it?